# Resharper localize complex strings

Tags: c#, localization, resharper, resource-files

How can I get Resharper to shove format strings into the resource file?  I have a MessageBox dialog that displays dynamic information like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(
    string.Format(
        "You have purchased '{0}' ({1}).  Currently, the value of {0} is {2:C}/ share.",
        stock.Symbol, stock.CompanyName, stock.ValuePerShare), Resources.FrmMain_btnVoting_Click_Vote_Purchase, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Note that the caption was easily localized to a resource file by Resharper, but I can't even get the option for the message body.  Does the format markup automatically make this string non-localizable?  I wouldn't think so.  I'd hate to have to write my own code to work with the resource file if I can figure out how to make Resharper just send it there like it did for the other string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to localize the message you can use the ***Move To Resource*** refactoring by pressing *Ctrl+R, Ctrl+O* after cursor was set on message string.